# TV show about cells living like humans do in our body

Tags: tv, story-identification

I can't remember this show about a blue humanoid cell and his robotic friend/sidekick who live like humans do but inside a human's body and try to stop other things from damaging the human's body.

Comment: Not what you are looking for, but related: [Moyashimon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyasimon:_Tales_of_Agriculture).

Comment: We've since had the same series asked after with, in my opinion, a better question and answer, so I closed the Duplicate in that direction.

Answer (score 9):

Found it, it's [Ozzy & Drix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozzy_&_Drix) had to search for the movie instead of the show directly to find it

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but you should edit it to include more information if you can.  It might be worth mentioning that this is a spin-off of the movie "Osmosis Jones."

Answer (score 3):

I think you look for ["Once Upon a Time… Life"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time..._Life) (French: Il était une fois… la vie), which perfectly fits your description.

Comment: No it's different the body is more urban with episodes such as a being turning into a monster representing an alergic reaction. If i remember right the main characters enter the boys body due to a mosquito sucking them up from another person and getting them stuck in the body. There's also a movie of them where the villian is salmonella if remember right. In real people played as humans while the cells kept there tv show look.